# gluLookAt implementation - zAxis orientation

Tags: math, opengl, linear-algebra

In the gluLookAt function `zAxis = target - cameraPosition` and then in a  view matrix we put `-zAxis` or we can write that `zAxis = cameraPosition - target` and then in a view matrix we put `zAxis` to get the same result. Why we have to negate zAxis in the first case or change order of operation in the second case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OpenGL, the standard camera space is a right-handed coordinate system. +X goes to the right, and +Y goes up. Because it's right-handed, +Z goes *behind* the viewer. Thus the viewer is looking along the *-Z axis*. Hence the negation.

Comment: So, when I don't use the gluLookAt function but I build my own view matrix using a camera position, xAxis, yAxis, zAxis (xAxis.x, xAxis.y, xAxis.z, -dot(xAxis, cameraPos), yAxis.x, yAxis.y, yAxis.z, -dot(yAxis, cameraPos), zAxis.x, zAxis.y, zAxis.z, -dot(zAxis, cameraPos, 0, 0, 0, 1) and then I just rotate those axes in my camera class I should define default xAxis, yAxis and zAxis this way: (1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1) ?